# I want to call Kotlin code from a Flutter app and take a screenshot, but I can't

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart

I wrote the following code and tried to implement a screenshot, but even though there is some byte data in the "image" variable, I cannot display it properly.

`MainActivity.kt`

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
import android.view.View

class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
    private val CHANNEL = "screenshot_channel"

override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
    super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)

    MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
        if (call.method == "takeScreenshot") {
            val bitmap = getScreenBitmap(flutterEngine)
            val byteArray = bitmapToByteArray(bitmap)

            result.success(byteArray)
        } else {
            result.notImplemented()
        }
    }
}

private fun getScreenBitmap(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine): Bitmap {
    val rootView = this@MainActivity.window.decorView.findViewById<View>(android.R.id.content)
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(rootView.width, rootView.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
    rootView.draw(canvas)
    return bitmap
}

    private fun bitmapToByteArray(bitmap: Bitmap): ByteArray {
        val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream)
        return stream.toByteArray()
    }
}
```

`main.dart`

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({super.key});
  static const platform = MethodChannel('screenshot_channel');
  Future<Image> _takeScreenshot() async {
    final Uint8List screenshot = await platform.invokeMethod('takeScreenshot');
    return Image.memory(screenshot);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: TextButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          final a = await _takeScreenshot();
          showCapturedWidget(context, a);
        },
        child: const Center(child: Text('show')),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Future<dynamic> showCapturedWidget(BuildContext context, Image? capturedImage) {
  return showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) => Container(
        color: Colors.amber,
        child: capturedImage != null
            ? Container(
                color: Colors.black,
                width: 50,
                height: 50,
                child: capturedImage,
              )
            : Container()),
  );
}
```

I am a beginner in Flutter and have no knowledge of Kotlin, so I don't know what's wrong. Could you please advise me if possible? I would appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: invoke your method with `try catch` ,  and please provide the error message.

Comment: No error message is printed.

Comment: this code is perfectly work, not getting any error @yamada

Comment: Whether an error occurs or not is not the measure of success or failure in programming.